# dropdownlist's Datavaluefield is not working

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

i am getting the datas from database and storing in a collectionobject. The collectionobj contains the Datas 'Name' and 'ID'.

My code:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="dropdown1" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"/>


collectionobj=objbs.GetNAmes()

for intloop as integer in Collectionobj.Count.Rows-1 

dropdown.Items.Add( Collectionobj.Items(intloop).Name)
dropdown.DataValueField=Collectionobj.Items(intloop).ID

Next
dropdown.DataBind()
```

Im getting the Value binded in the dropdown as "Names" . when i select the dropdown i need to pass the respective ID of that name.

But when I assign the

```
Dim strid as String=dropdown1.DataValueField
```

The `dropdown1.DataValueField` is holding the id of last name binded in the dropdown.it is not taking the id which im selecting  n the dropdown..

Any suggestion..........

Comment: Your code is a mess, and trying to format it just makes it all that much more evident. VB.NET will automatically capitalize most of those identifiers, so that tells me you're not copying and pasting this from the IDE, which is your first mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SelectedValue property not DataValueField property to get the curent selected value.

```
Dim strid as String=dropdown1.SelectedValue
```

Since you mentioned getNAmes returns a colection, you can replace the code to populate the dropdown with this:

```
collectionobj=objbs.GetNAmes()
dropdown.DataSource=Collectionobj //The datanamefield and value field are specified in aspx file.
dropdown.DataBind()


To get the Selected Text use: dropdown.SelectedItem.Text
To get the Selected Value use: dropdown.SelectedItem.Value or dropdown.SelectedValue
```

Comment: but the dropdown1.SelectedValue is even giving me oly the Name. and not the ID . for eg. it is giving me oly 'XXX' and not the repective '1' id.

Comment: What does objbs.GetNAmes() return?

Comment: collectionobject with all the property values set to it

Comment: tnks for yr rwply. even i tried this the value in strid is simply the text "id" when i use this code . Dim strid as String=dropdown1.DataValueField

Comment: As I mentioned earlier you should use dropDown.SelectedValue not DataValueField.

Comment: ok. if i use that it will give me the respective id???. and not the name in the dropdownlist??.Tnks yaar... lt me try it..

Comment: To get the name you should use dropDown.SelectedItem.Text